# Can we add a @Suppress flag globally?

Tags: android, kotlin, suppress-warnings

In kotlin, if we use a `when` block on an enum while exhausting all the enum values but without adding an `else` branch, we get this warning: "Enum argument can be null in Java, but exhaustive when contains no null branch".

Android Studio then suggest to add the suppress flag `@Suppress("WHEN_ENUM_CAN_BE_NULL_IN_JAVA")` either to the statement, function, class or file scope.

Is there any way to add this to the project scope ? Since my project is 100% Kotlin I don't need this warning and would like to disable it globally.

Comment: see https://proandroiddev.com/til-when-is-when-exhaustive-31d69f630a8b